# git svn clone for a non-standard layout

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, git-clone

I have a SVN repo that I need to move to GIT. For historical reasons that predate my role and that I cannot resolve, the layout is as follows (let's call the project "project" for lack of a better term):

```
project/trunk
project/tags
project/branches
```

Standard layout. The problem is that the trunk was never updated, not in a long time. Neither tags, so that's useless.

The real meat and potatoes is under project/branches, as follows:

```
project/branches/branch1 (starts at revision r1)
project/branches/branch2 (starts at revision r2)
... 
project/branches/branch_W (starts at revision r_w)
...
project/branches/branch_X (starts at revision r_w)
...
project/branches/branch_Y (starts at revision r_y)
...
project/branches/branch_Z (starts at revision r_z)
```

The way branches were created was by branching (`branch_child`) directly from another branch (`branch_parent`), rather than branching from trunk (after trunk being updated/rebased with `branch_parent`).

Also, `branch_parent` might have been deleted, and there are a lot of dead-end branches.

In this example, I want to get branch_W ... branch_Z, with branch_W at revision_w as the start of the revision range. In my case, I need to do this with about a dozen branches created in such a fashion.)

Anyone that could suggest an efficient (or at best, least pain-inducing) way to get git svn clone to accomplish this?

Worst come to worst, I'd just git svn clone the most recent branch (I can do that.) But I find it extremely important to bring all the history from the branches I'm interested in.

Thanks.

Comment: My advice is to go via an "inefficient" way: `git svn clone` using the standard layout and rename/remove/rebase branches using `git`.

Comment: I see. I was hoping for a shortcut since this thing is massive :/

Answer (score 0):

I gave up, the original structure is way too convoluted/mismanaged and the log history too long to even try to do this.

The solution suggested by @phd (to git svn clone using the standard layout) could have worked under normal circumstances.

So I am left with git svn'ing the most recent branch and take it as the trunk/master.